# vb.net smooth and slow charting

Tags: vb.net, winforms, charts

Having `Chart1` in **VB.NET Application** , how to draw points slowly and smoothly?

Trying to find out answer before posting a question; it looks users looking for fast chart for performance, but for demonstration reasons I am looking for a way to chart data slowly.

Having this code works but not smoothly and I am not sure how it will work for 1K of points for example , also how to give user choice of speeding/slowing the chart drawing.

```
Module Module1
Function SlowChart() As Boolean  
' ... some code  
While dr.Read ' reading x,y from datareader
        Dim x As DateTime = CType(dr.Item(3), DateTime)
        Dim y As Integer = CType(dr.Item(4), Integer)
        Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(x, y)
        Chart1.Update()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(300) ' pause drawing; but looks like app hanging a little
    End While 
'...somecode
Return True
End Function
End Module
```

**Update**: Update code structure.

Thank you

Comment: Use a  [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)'s `Tick` event handler to add your points to the chart.  You can change the `Interval` property to adjust the speed.  Add one point per tick.

Comment: Thank you @TnTinMn, but can't make timer work from within `module`. variables are `Dim` locally in function and `timer` object can't read them.

Comment: Thank you for your help.